# Slim Framework and .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, basic-authentication, slim

I don't know what I am doing wrong but if I add a .htaccess protection to my directory with the following content my SLIM application won't work:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "no entry"
AuthUserFile /www/html/management/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

without this .htaccess file it works :(. The directory tree looks as follows

```
html/
    management/
        index.php
        .htaccess (with the content above)
        .htpasswd
        api/
            Slim/
            index.php
            .htaccess
```

The .htaccess file in the api directory looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /management/api    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Hope you can help me, because I don't know why my application not working :(.

**EDIT:**

If I var_dump the required object which is responsible for the data output. I am getting the following result:

"This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required."

Comment: This is kind of obvious, but If you add basic authentication you must provide username and password with the request.

Comment: ok thanks, do you know how can I realize this?

Comment: Depends on what kind of client you are using to access the api.  Browser should ask the password. With libraries you can pass credentials somewhere in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the second .htaccess works for me

```
Satisfy any
allow from all
```